# un expexted behaviour of javascript constructor when called without new keyword

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I created a class using function like -

```js
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

var obj = new Person("Ferdinand");

console.log(obj.name);
```

I am creating an object obj and prints its property name it is working fine and prints "Ferdinand", but if we forget to write new key word like below program -

```js
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

var obj = Person("Ferdinand");

console.log(name);
```

Here I am not able to understand why name is available in console, it is printing "Ferdinand". But we are using Person as a function and assigning name variable in function itself so why its value is available outside function.

Comment: Because without `new` the `this` keyword refers to the `window` object and `window.name = name` sets a global variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript), specifically [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1646957/502381)

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript does not implement objects in the classical sense. Instead, they are implemented directly:

```
var thing={};   //  new object
```

Because you typically want multiple objects to follow a common pattern and behaviour, you can use what is called a **constructor** function to help. In your example, `Person` is a constructor function.

When using a constructor, you call it *indirectly* using the `new` command:

```
var thing = new Person(…);
```

In fact, there’s a lot of magic going on here:

- JavaScript begins by creating a new object: `var thing={};`.
- Then the `this` key word is assigned to the new object
- Finally the constructor is run, using the `this` value to assign local values.

If you call a constructor function *directly*, the first 2 steps do not apply, and the function is left trying to work in its own definition of `this` which is generally not what you want.

If you really want to call the constructor function without bothering with `new`, you can try the following:

```
function Person(data) {
    //  “new” safe constructor
    if(!(this instanceof Person)) {
    return new Person(data);
}
```

This new version checks whether it is being called as a proper constructor, and, if not, calls itself properly.